# My gas heater relief valve keeps blowing, is the circulator installed backwards?

Tags: water, heating, heater

So I had a contractor put in a new circulator last season.  Its a honeywell PC3F.  I tried turning my heater on for the first time this season and the relief valve blew.  I tried replacing that and the new one blew.  This has never happened before. so I wonder if it has something to do with what the contractor did.  He also added a small expansion tank to the unit and routed water away from the old expansion tank which rotted out.  The hot water does not reach the radiators.

This is a long shot but could the contractor have installed the circulator backwards?  I noticed the writing on the front of the device is upside down and I don't think it was meant to be.

[image: circulator]
[image: heater]

Comment: Are there any pressure gauges on the system? Do you have a gauge to read the pressure? Was the expansion tank charged to the proper pressure? There should be an arrow on the pump assembly that points in the direction of flow, is it pointing the right way? Why was the pump replaced? Is the new expansion tank the same size as the old one (volume wise, not necessarily size wise)?

Comment: Could you include some photos?

Comment: Ill put some photos up in a few mins.  the pressure read very high. I should also say it's a manual fill tank.  The expansion tank is smaller.  Crap... I just checked.  The arrow is pointing down back toward the heater.

Comment: ok pic up.  Is that the way the pump is supposed to be facing?

Comment: Sure looks like the pump is backwards to me. You might want to contact the company that installed the pump, they *may* (*should*) come fix their mistake free of charge.

Comment: What is the make and model of the boiler?

Comment: peerless MMW-60A-WC